# Can I add a Play 2 application to an existing WAR?

Tags: gwt, servlets, playframework-2.0

I have a servlet-based Java application (to be more precise: a [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) application with a standard [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) Java backend). I want to add a REST API and would like to use the [Play 2 Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) for this. Is this possible?

I do not mind if the servlet runs on one port (8080, say) and the Play web server on another (8081, say).

(*Background:* On the long run, I will migrate my whole application to Play and Akka actors. Therefore, I would like to already use Play for the REST API to be developed.)